# Finding determinant of a 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Assuming y is a nonzero real number, I need to find the determinant of this matrix:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
1 & y & y^2 \\
y & y^2 & y^3 \\
 y^2 & y^3 & y^4
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Can anyone help me get started? I know the answer is 0 from using Mathematica. Thanks

**Edit**

If I pulled out y from a row and had

$$y*D \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
1 & y & y^2 \\
1 & y & y^2 \\
 y^2 & y^3 & y^4
    \end{array}
\right] $$

and $$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
1 & y & y^2 \\
1 & y & y^2 \\
 y^2 & y^3 & y^4
    \end{array}
\right]  = 0$$

therefore,

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
1 & y & y^2 \\
y & y^2 & y^3 \\
 y^2 & y^3 & y^4
    \end{array}
\right] = 0$$

is this correct?

Comment: Use the formula you (should) have been given for the determinant of a 3-by-3 matrix...

Comment: We're not supposed to use the permutation formula

Comment: Not to bring back an ancient question, but definitely check out Lewis Carroll (the author of Alice in Wonderland)'s condensation method. It is my favorite. (AKA Dodgson condensation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Pick two rows (or two columns). Are they linearly independent?

Comment: I updated my answer, is this right?

Comment: The last two lines should be the determinant of the matrix is equal to zero, not the matrix itself.

Comment: Ah yes, that is what I wrote down, just forgot to type it in. Thanks for the help